# Youtube search api parse issue

Tags: ios, xml, xcode, rss, youtube

I am developing youtube IOS application. I want to get video image on response.

Here is response part,

```
"media:thumbnail" =         (
                        {
                "@height" = 360;
                "@time" = "00:00:51.500";
                "@url" = "http://i.ytimg.com/vi/S8OG7dN-66Q/0.jpg";
                "@width" = 480;
            },
                        {
                "@height" = 90;
                "@time" = "00:00:25.750";
                "@url" = "http://i.ytimg.com/vi/S8OG7dN-66Q/1.jpg";
                "@width" = 120;
            },
                        {
                "@height" = 90;
                "@time" = "00:00:51.500";
                "@url" = "http://i.ytimg.com/vi/S8OG7dN-66Q/2.jpg";
                "@width" = 120;
            },
                        {
                "@height" = 90;
                "@time" = "00:01:17.250";
                "@url" = "http://i.ytimg.com/vi/S8OG7dN-66Q/3.jpg";
                "@width" = 120;
            }
        );
```

I want get @url tag value but I did not

Thnx

Comment: Can you elaborate a bit more? What is the response?

Comment: I did try for get media:thumbnail datas like this But I got null - NSLog(@"%@",[(NSDictionary*)[self.arrayTmp objectAtIndex:i] objectForKey:@"media:thumbnail"]);